# CSS is not loading up completely in root folder

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am facing an issue with our website css, the website in the root folder is not parsing the css correctly, while the same set of files in the subfolder is being displayed correctly,

Issue Link : [This website is not appearing right](http://www.cloudcandyhost.com/index1.html)  -

Sub folder link : [In the Sub Folder its appearing right](http://www.cloudcandyhost.com/website)

The root and the sub folder contains exactly the same files and codes. Please can anyone check and help us out by pointing out errors.

I do not understand much of the format of stackoverflow , so kindly understand and help out. Let me know if you need any other info regarding this issue.

Comment: Just tried to find any difference between the 2 links you provided, can't find anyone.

Comment: No difference here either.

Comment: Attaching the screenshots *[this is proper](http://cloudcandyhost.com/2.png)     *[this link is not](http://cloudcandyhost.com/1.png)

Comment: Sorry understood the issue. It was due to cloudflare. Thankyou for the help :)